# Change border color on <select> HTML form

Tags: html, css, html-select

Is it possible to change the border color on a `<select/>` element in an HTML form?

The `border-color` style works in Firefox but not IE.

I could find no real answers on Google.

Comment: which version of IE? it does work but there are some known issues.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I would consinder enclosing that select block within a div block and setting the border property like this:

```html
<div style="border: 2px solid blue;">
  <select style="width: 100%;">
    <option value="Sal">Sal</option>
    <option value="Awesome">Awesome!</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

You should be able to play with that to accomplish what you need.

Comment: Umm... wasn't that what I suggested too? Okay, maybe I didn't <b>show</b> how to do it. ;-)

Comment: Cerebrus: As I posted this answer I noticed you had posted the suggestion as well, so for that I voted up your answer. :)

Comment: This article explains the technique in a bit more detail, and has a demo http://swatelier.info/at/forms/selectExp.htm

Comment: adding the property "border: 2px solid blue" to the select style worked as well.

Answer (score 6):

As Diodeus stated, IE doesn't allow anything but the default border for `<select>` elements. However, I know of two hacks to achieve a similar effect :

1. Use a DIV that is placed absolutely at the same position as the dropdown and set it's borders. It will appear that the dropdown has a border.
2. Use a Javascript solution, for instance, the one provided [here](http://webfx.eae.net/dhtml/select/jsGenerated.html).

It may however prove to be too much effort, so you should evaluate if you really require the border.

Answer (score 4):

No, the `<select>` control is a system-level control, not a client-level control in IE. A few versions back it didn't even play nicely-with z-index, putting itself on top of virtually everything.

To do anything fancy you'll have to emulate the functionality using CSS and your own elements.

Comment: It being a system-level control or not doesn't make up for the fact that you can't style it (properly) though. I.e it doesnt pose onovercomeable challenges for the IE team even if it was.

Comment: OwnerDrawing is ever so much fun though ;)

Comment: Thanks for confirmation of the system-level control thing.

Answer (score 2):

```
select{
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=-1, OffY=-1,color=#FF0000) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=1, OffY=1,color=#FF0000);
}
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

<del>You can set the border color in IE however there are some issues.</del>

Argh... I could have sworn you could do this... just tested and realized I wasn't correct. The notes below still apply though.

1. in IE8 (Beta1 -> RC1) changing the border color or the background color/image causes a de-theming of the control in WindowsXP (the drop arrow and box look like Windows 95)
2. you still can't style the options within the select control very well because IE doesn't support it. ([see bug #291](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/11/bug-291-no-styling-options-in-ie.html))

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the border-color with outline-color should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.form-error {
        border: 2px solid #e74c3c;
    }
</style>



<div class="form-error">
                                {!! Form::select('color', $colors->prepend('Please Select Color', ''),           ,['class' => 'form-control dropselect form-error'
                                ,'tabindex' => $count++, 'id' => 'color']) !!}
                                </div>
```