# How to remove boostrap multiselect border color

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to remove border color from options of a select box from bootstrap multiselect, but unable to find any class which is adding a blue color around the border of the options.

This border comes when you click on the option or you put it into focus, here is what I have tried

HTML

```
<body>
    <select size="5" name="lstStates" multiple="multiple" id="lstStates">
        <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
        <option value="NY">New York</option>
        <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
        <option value="TX">Texas</option>
        <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
        <option value="GG">asdfa</option>
        <option value="AW">jghjh</option>
        <option value="AE">qwer</option>
    </select>   
</body>
```

jquery

```
$(function () { 
    $('#lstStates').multiselect({ 
        buttonText: function(options, select) {
            console.log(select[0].length);
            if (options.length === 0) {
                return 'None selected';
            }
            if (options.length === select[0].length) {
                return 'All selected ('+select[0].length+')';
            }
            else if (options.length >=10) {
                return options.length + ' selected';
            }
            else {
                var labels = [];
                console.log(options);
                options.each(function() {
                    labels.push($(this).val());
                });
                return labels.join(', ') + '';
            }
        }

    });
});
```

css

```
.dropdown-menu>.active>a, .dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover, .dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus {
    color: #20262e;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.15);
    outline: 0;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
    color: #262626;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.15);
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/emozsaurab/8o36Leqw/1/)

[image]

Comment: http://www.outlinenone.com/ By removing this you're actively making your site less accessible.

Comment: See If this question answered your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492627/change-border-color-on-select-html-form

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the border highlight on an input text element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457849/how-to-remove-the-border-highlight-on-an-input-text-element)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The blue is caused by the user-agent stylesheet:

```
:focus {
    outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;
}
```

you can override it just on your dropdown with:

```
ul.multiselect-container li a:focus
{
    outline-color: white;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/76wdfrbm/

Answer (score 0):

I added outline: 0; to .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus and it worked

```
 .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
    color: #262626;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.15);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add this CSS in your code:

```
.dropdown-menu>li>a label:focus{outline: none}
.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus{outline: none}
```

Answer (score 0):

by default, the browser use this style

```
  :focus {
    outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;
}
```

you can override the elements

```
.multiselect-container>li>a>label.checkbox:focus{
    outline:0 !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
a,a:focus{
    outline:none;
}
```

this will remove focus border

Answer (score -1):

**you should apply below style:**

```
<style>
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
outline:none;
}
</style>
```